# Filter column A if another value is present in column B

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two columns

| Store | Code |
| --- | --- |
| Store1.DD | 101 |
| Store2.DE | 103 |
| Store2.DD | 103 |
| Store1.DD | 105 |
| Store2.DD | 107 |

I want to filter all the stores that has the value DD and Codes 101 and 103

I wrote this query

```
 Select * from table 
where Store not like '%DD' and Code not in ('101,'103')
```

But the issue is that its excluding all the the DD stores now. I only want to filter DD when both values are present. How can I do that?

Expected results:

| Store | Code |
| --- | --- |
| Store2.DE | 103 |
| Store1.DD | 105 |
| Store2.DD | 107 |

Comment: Please show more sample input and add the expected result.

Comment: I don't understand your explanation. Do you merely want to exclude rows with DD/101 and DD/103 from your result? Or do you want to exclude those rows only when the store also has a row with another code than 101 and 103? Or something else still?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT [Store]
      ,[Code]
  FROM [dbo].[Store]
  WHERE not (Store like '%DD' and Code in ('101', '103'))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE Store NOT LIKE '%DD' OR Code NOT IN ('101', '103')
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score -1):

In your giving example you can just change the logic from `AND` to `OR`

```
SELECT * FROM table  
WHERE Code NOT IN (101,103) OR Store NOT LIKE '%DD'
```

Comment: You wrong, try this.

Comment: Ah sorry you are right.